# Is there any way to run to run Karate feature files programatically from java code

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, cucumber, karate

I have a requirement to run karate feature files when someone invokes specifically to run them. So I want to run it programmatically from java code.
I have tried running karate feature files as JUnit files programmatically but they do not generate reports.
Can anyone please help me!

Comment: if the linked answer does not help, please assume that what you are asking for is not supported by karate, so you may need to build this kind of integration on your own